# Why QSqlDatabase object won't work if addDatabase method assigned later?

Tags: c++, qt, qsqldatabase

This won't work:

```
{
    QSqlDatabase db;
    db.addDatabase("QSQLITE", "manDb");
    QString path = QDir::currentPath()+"/"+"Sqlite.db";
    db.setDatabaseName(path);
    if(db.open())
    {
        qDebug()<< "Database Created successfully...";

    }else{
        qDebug()<< "Failed to create Database...";
    }
}
QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase("manDb");
```

> **Output:** Failed to create Database...

But this works:

```
{
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE", "manDb");
    QString path = QDir::currentPath()+"/"+"Sqlite.db";
    db.setDatabaseName(path);
    if(db.open())
    {
        qDebug()<< "Database Created successfully...";

    }else{
        qDebug()<< "sucessfully Failed to create Database...";
    }
}
QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase("manDb");
```

> **Output:** Database Created successfully...

Why?

Answer (score 0):

Your first code sample does not work because according to [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsqldatabase.html#QSqlDatabase)
`QSqlDatabase db;`

> Creates an empty, invalid QSqlDatabase object. Use addDatabase(), removeDatabase(), and database() to get valid QSqlDatabase objects.

Then you try to call static [QSqlDatabase::addDatabase](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsqldatabase.html#addDatabase) method with `db.addDatabase("QSQLITE", "manDb");` which returns QSqlDatabase class instance, but you do not assign it's return value to variable to use it later.

> Adds a database to the list of database connections using the driver type and the connection name connectionName. If there already exists a database connection called connectionName, that connection is removed.

> The database connection is referred to by connectionName. The newly
> added database connection is returned.

So, in the first sample you tried to use QSqlDatabase in wrong way. Meanhile your second sample is a correct usage.